# Why does the mediaplayer.prepareAsync() throw an IllegalStateException?

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer, alarm, illegalstateexception

Here is my Activity:

```
public class AlarmPlayerActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener {
    private MediaPlayer player;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_alarm_player);
        int alarm_number = getIntent().getIntExtra(Config.KEY_ALARM_NO, 0);
        ((TextView) findViewById(R.id.alarm_message)).setText(getString(R.string.alarms_was_set).concat(": " + alarm_number));
    }

    public void stopPlayingAlarm(View view) {
        if (player != null && player.isPlaying()) {
            player.reset();
            player.stop();
            player.release();
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        Uri uri = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_ALARM);
        player = MediaPlayer.create(this, uri);
        player.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_ALARM);
        player.setLooping(true);
        player.setOnPreparedListener(this);
        player.prepareAsync();
    }

    @Override
    public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
        mp.start();
    }
}
```

But it throws `IllegalStateException` on `player.prepareAsync()` call.

I cannot fix it although I have tried other answers found in this site.

Note that, this activity is launched from a broadcast receiver which is triggered by an `RTC_WAKEUP` alarm.

Here is part of my AndroidManifest :

```
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.EXPAND_STATUS_BAR" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.android.alarm.permission.SET_ALARM" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FOREGROUND_SERVICE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MODIFY_AUDIO_SETTINGS"/>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MediaPlayer already had prepare() inside. So if you call a second prepare(), it will throw exception.

[Link official doc](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer#create(android.content.Context,%252520android.net.Uri,%252520android.view.SurfaceHolder))

Answer (score 3):

Hi its late to answer but i think you need some more explanation supporting @Miller's answer.

You are Creating **MediaPlayer** instance using `static MediaPlayer create (Context context, Uri uri)` method. This method will assign audioSessionId for you by calling `prepare()` by itself.

```
Note that since prepare() is called automatically in this method, you cannot change the audio session ID
```

So Clearly, You cann't edit its audioSessionID. whereas when you call `player.prepareAsync();` it requests new sessionId. which results in `illegalStateException`. [see docx](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html#create(android.content.Context,%2520android.net.Uri))